# When do i need to download the .Net core Runtime?

Tags: .net-core, download, sdk, runtime

From [this](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download#/sdk) link, we can download Core SDK and Runtime. I understand that SDK includes runtime.  But in what situation i should download the .Net Core Runtime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to run an .Net Core application, you need the runtime. If you want to build .Net Core apps you need the SDK(which includes runtime). But if you build a .Net Core app that is self-contained, you wouldn't even need the runtime for running it. 
Lets say you have 2 Computers, on one you will create your app and you want to run the app on the other computer. On the first computer you would need the SDK, and on the other computer you would only need the runtime. But if you built your app as a self-contained one, you wouldn't need the runtime either on the second computer. 
Hope this helps.