# How to run my c# console application on someone else's computer

Tags: c#

So a really basic question:
I wrote a c# console app. Not completly basic. There several classes outside the Programm.cs.
Now I wanted to show it to some friends so I send them zipped folder and and told them to go into \bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1 and open the .exe file.
This works for me, but not for 2 of my friends who tried it.

A new windows opens and closes right away.

They seem to have the .Net framework installed.
Is there a way to open it without having install visual studio?
Thanks
Solved:
The issue was that .Net Core Desktop Runtime wasn't installed
Thanks everyone

Comment: Is there a .sln file. That should be ran if it is visual studio.

Comment: If your program crashes on launch, you need to add logging or something similar to catch the problem.

Comment: Do a release build, just to rule out problems specifically associated with debug builds looking for debug libraries (.NET doesn't do this as much as say C++ but you still want to rule that out)

Comment: As an aside, if you have a .NET Core application, .NET Framework is irrelevant.

Comment: There isn't enough detail in your question to know for sure why the program doesn't run. But the duplicate describes what components are required on a computer for different scenarios. In your own case, as long as you compile the project as a self-contained executable, and the other computer has the .NET Core _runtime_ installed (no need for the SDK, and certainly no need for Visual Studio), it will run. Whether the program _works_ or not depends on what's actually in the program. There's so little detail in your question, we can't even tell whether you have a bug in the program itself.

Comment: If you have a .NET program that quits before displaying the main window, chances are that the runtime has made an entry in the Windows "Application" event log.  Right-click start menu, pick "Event Viewer" from the menu, navigate to the Application event log and look for anything related to .NET or your app.

Comment: There's likely detail in that console window that blips on and off. If you have them run it from the command line, that helpful detail will stick around to aid in troubleshooting.

Answer (score -1):

You should publish your project. You will find the option to publish based on your visual studio.

Once your code is published, open \bin\release\netcoreapp3.1\publish..

And share this complete published folder

Comment: I don't think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552782/when-do-i-need-to-download-the-net-core-runtime question has really answered the question. as there was technical issue in sharing the content in current question. That question answers why we need runtime but problem here is even if we have runtime, how we can share the code with others.